# Axis equal image key and z log mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Suppose we want plot something like this

[image]

with code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%set a compat!!
%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={f(\x,\y)=exp(-10*(x^2+y^2));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={H(\x,\y) = .125297/(sqrt((\x^4-6*\x^2*\y^2+\y^4+.581580*\x^3-1.744740*\x*\y^2+1.169118*\x^2-1.169118*\y^2+.404768*\x+.176987)^2+(4*\x^3*\y-4*\x*\y^3+1.744740*\x^2*\y-.581580*\y^3+2.338236*\x*\y+.404768*\y)^2));}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[       
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    width=20cm, %%ridi velikost grafu! 
    view={50}{20},      
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=0.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    miter limit=1,   
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    zlabel style={anchor=north east},% <- position the z label
    xtick = {0},
    xticklabels = {0},
    ytick = \empty,  
    ztick = \empty,
    ]


    \addplot3[      
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.1pt, 
        fill=white,
        domain=0:0.5,
        y domain = 0:1.5,
        samples = 20,
        samples y = 20,
        restrict z to domain*=0:1.5]
        {H(x,y)};

     \addplot3[domain=0:1.5,samples=70, samples y = 0, red, thick] ({0},{x},{H(0,x)});

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What if I would like to plot it with `zmode=log key` in axis environment. It gives this
[image]

How to make it behave normal? I mean having equal scaling except for z axis (which is log scaled)?

Comment: The [restrict z to domain*=0:1.5] appears to be applied AFTER the conversion to log scale.  Dropping it works.

Comment: I don't get it. [restrict z to domain*=0:1.5] is in addplot command, but the zmode-log in axis environement. Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, ALL of the log z values are less than zero.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%set a compat!!
%%%%%%% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={f(\x,\y)=exp(-10*(x^2+y^2));}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={H(\x,\y) = .125297/(sqrt((\x^4-6*\x^2*\y^2+\y^4+.581580*\x^3-1.744740*\x*\y^2+1.169118*\x^2-1.169118*\y^2+.404768*\x+.176987)^2+(4*\x^3*\y-4*\x*\y^3+1.744740*\x^2*\y-.581580*\y^3+2.338236*\x*\y+.404768*\y)^2));}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[       
    axis lines=middle, axis on top,
    axis equal image,
    width=20cm, %%ridi velikost grafu! 
    view={50}{20},      
    xmin=-0.5,
    xmax=0.5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2,
    zmin=0,
    zmax=2,
    miter limit=1,   
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    zlabel=$z$,
    zlabel style={anchor=north east},% <- position the z label
    xtick = {0},
    xticklabels = {0},
    ytick = \empty,  
    ztick = \empty,
    zmode=log
    ]

    \addplot3[      
        smooth,
        surf,
        faceted color=black,
        line width=0.1pt, 
        fill=white,
        domain=0:0.5,
        y domain = 0:1.5,
        samples = 20,
        samples y = 20,
        %restrict z to domain*=0:1.5,
        ]
        {H(x,y)};

    \addplot3[ domain=0:1.5, samples=70, samples y=0, red, thick] (0,x,{H(0,x)});

    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```